# Error Lagrange interpolation on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, numerical-methods, numerical-calculus

The Lagrange interpolation on $\mathbb{R}^2$ of $f\in\mathcal{C}^{2}([a,b]\times[c,d])$ is defined as:
$$f(x,y)\approx\sum_{m=0}^M \sum_{n=0}^{N}L_{n,m}(x,y) f(x_n,y_m),\qquad N,M\in\mathbb{N},$$
where $\{x_n\}$ is a partition of $[a,b]$, $\{y_m\}$ is a partition of $[c,d]$, and
$$L_{n,m}(x,y)=\prod_{j=0,j\neq n}^N\dfrac{x-x_j}{x_{j+1}-x_j}\prod_{l=0,l\neq m}^M\dfrac{y-y_l}{y_{l+1}-y_l}.$$

If we consider the particular case of the Lagrange interpolation on $\mathbb{R}$, the error for $x\in[a,b]$ is
$$E(x)=f(x)-H(x)=\dfrac{f''(\xi)}{2}\prod_{n=0}^N(x-x_n),\qquad \xi\in(a,b),$$
where
$$H(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{M}f(x_n)\prod_{j=0,j\neq n}^N\dfrac{x-x_n}{x_{n+1}-x_n},\qquad N\in\mathbb{N}.$$

Then, I am wondering if there is a formula for the two dimensional case.

Comment: No, for the same reason mean-value theorem is actually an inequality not an equality, in higher dimensions.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So, is there an inequality at least?

Comment: Yes.  See e.g. [Corollary 3.11 here](https://community.ams.org/journals/mcom/1995-64-211/S0025-5718-1995-1297477-5/S0025-5718-1995-1297477-5.pdf).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you.